# getBeansOfType inside a Configuration Class

Tags: java, spring, configuration, javabeans, applicationcontext

I have a problem with my Spring Classes. I need to get all Beans of a type inside a Configuration class to give them to a another class.

The Problem now is, that I cant do that unless I startup a `ApplicationContext` but that doesn't work, because the Config class I call up uses the config class I'm calling from, so I get a endless loop...

as example:

```
@Configuration
@Import(Calling.class)
public class MyConfig{
@Bean
public ExampleClass aBean(){
...
return aObject;
}
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
@Import(MyConfig.class)
public class Calling{

@Bean
public Foo anotherBean(){
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(myConfig.class);
ctx.getBeansOfType(ExampleClass.class);
return aObject;
}
}
```

Is there any functionality or pattern I can use to get these Beans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `@Configuration`, you need to be very careful not to "pull" beans from the context, since you often get these infinite loops.

Try this instead:

```
@Configuration
@Import(Calling.class)
public class MyConfig {
   @Bean
   public ExampleClass aBean() {
      ...
      return aObject;
   }
}
```

---

```
@Configuration
public class Calling {

   private @Autowired List<ExampleClass> exampleBeans;

   @Bean
   public Foo anotherBean() {
      return aObject;
   }
}
```

This declarative approach should hopefully get around the infinite loop problem.

Note also, you should avoid cyclic `@Import`. Do it in one direction only, as in the above example.

Comment: okay, seems quite good but: i cant create the `Calling` class because it depends on `MyConfig` Class... when i startup my App, the `MyConfig` class is loaded, then `Calling` is imported BUT at this point `MyConfig` does not exists yet, so `Calling` wants the `ExampleClasses` but fails here...

Comment: i solved it now this way: i created a `List<ExampleClass>` and initilized it with an empty list. Also i created a Method `setList(List<ExampleClass>)` which is `@Autowired`. In this class i use the `List.addAll(Collection)` Method to set the Content. The List is now available for all using methods, even after its written by Spring.

Answer (score 0):

you could use LazyInitTargetSource unless method(s) must be called on both beans on context initialization

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/aop/target/LazyInitTargetSource.html

(otherwise it'd be best to remove the circular dependency if possible)

Comment: `@Lazy` seems also quite good, but the beans are processed before the `@Autowired` is injected...